how to find closed form for ${}_3F_2(-1)$ function identity?
I tried to prove this identity I got it from wolfram functions site
$$\Omega_a={}_3F_2(1,1,a;2,3-a;-1)=\frac{2-a}{2(1-a)} H_{1-a} $$
firstly from its series I got that
$$ \Omega_a=\frac{\Gamma(3-a)}{\Gamma(a)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(n+3-a)} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$$
then its easy to show that
$$\Omega_a=\frac{1}{\beta(a,3-2a)} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-2}}{(1-x)^{2a-2}}\ln(x+1)dx $$
from the result of $\Omega_a$ in the site we have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{x} \right)^{a}\ln(x+1)dx =\frac{1}{2} \beta(1-a,1+2a) \left(1+\frac{1}{a} \right)H_a$$
Now how to prove this last integral?
I tried by a lot of methods but if fails and I searched on MSE but didn't find any information about this integral.

I would like to note that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}(\frac{(1-x)^2}{x})^a\ln(x+1)$ has a pole at $(x=0\wedge a>0)\vee(x=1\wedge a<0)$ and Mathematica says $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=e^{a\infty}$ aka $\infty$ for $a>0$ aka it's integral should not exist. If $a<0$ then taking $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ gives also $\infty$. You can see this easily via it's plot.

One issue with the bare series representation here is that, if $a$ is a negative integer, then $\Gamma(n+a)$ diverges when $n=-a$. (In reality, the Pochhammer symbols cause the series to truncate at $n=-a$. The conversion to the Gamma function form obscures this.) That doesn't rule out this approach entirely, but it does suggest that this route is perhaps not ideal.

@KevinDietrich the integral exist for $|x|<1 , x\ne \frac{-1}{2}$

@Semiclassical maybe using $(a)n=\lim{x\to a} \frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}$ will help which mean gamma of negative integer/ gamma of negative integer does exist by limits .
